# What is the use of a session store?

Tags: node.js, session, koa

I am using koa and passport therefore I am using the [koa-generic-session](https://github.com/koajs/generic-session) middleware to handle my sessions.

Now unlike the expressjs [session](https://github.com/expressjs/session) middleware there isn't a big disclaimer in the documentation like such : ***The default server-side session storage, MemoryStore, is purposely not designed for a production environment.***

Assuming the MemoryStore for the koa-generic-session is ready for production use, why would I use a heavy duty session store such as mysql or mongodb for sessions that come and go all day long? What additional capabilities would using one give me that MemoryStore doesn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In memory session store works perfectly for development but it has a couple of caviats for production use.

- restarting the server causes all sessions to be invalidated, this is not nice for the users of your application
- in memory store is not efficient handling production level loads where there are potentially huge amounts of sessions ongoing at the same time, therefore a more efficient storage is better that writes to disks, caches frequently used. a database would fulfill all these qualities

Comment: hi, does that mean i have to write something to clean up dead sessions off the database or is it automatic?

Comment: No big reason to clean them up. It's good to have a record of old/historic sessions. Though once your sessions table has millions of rows, you might consider pruning out old ones just to make it less unwieldy.

Comment: oldest unused ones should cleaned to avoid the store expanding forever, but i had high hopes that the session store implementation would handle that automatically for you